# Attached Property defined in static class not working

Tags: wpf, binding

I'm having a bit of a problem with attached behaviours. I want to supply a Binding to a Dependency Property, but the value isn't known until the ViewModel is initialized, so the Setter fails.

Currently, I have this code:

```
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type visi:Chart}">
                <Setter Property="att:ChartBehaviour.ExecuteCommandOnDoubleClick" Value="true"/>
                <Setter Property="att:ChartBehaviour.ShowHideCommand" Value="{Binding OverviewHideCommand}"/>
            </Style>
```

The first setter works perfectly fine, but the second one doesn't, as the `OverviewHideCommand` won't be available (ie. is `null` at the point of style application) until the backing object is constructed.

Any pointers on how to work around this? I'd really like to stay in xaml if possible.

**Edit:**

The problem apperently is in the definition of `ShowHideCommand`, which is defined as attached property (the class is in a different namespace than the xaml itself, but the xaml references the namespace):

```
public static class ChartBehaviour
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowHideCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ShowHideCommand", 
                                            typeof(ICommand), 
                                            typeof(Chart), 
                                            new PropertyMetadata(new DefaultCommand()));
}
```

Interestingly, the property is not appearing the in the `Chart` class. How should I change the definition for it to appear in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem. Actually, it was two problems.

First: The attached property was defined for `Chart`, not `ChartBehaviour`.

After that it parsed correctly and started. Then the second problem turned up - the event I specified the following:

```
static void OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var obj = e.OriginalSource as Visifire.Charts.Chart;

    if (obj == null)
        return;

    GetShowHideCommand(obj).Execute(null);
}
```

The problem was this line: `var obj = e.OriginalSource as Visifire.Charts.Chart;`. The Chart is a very complex object, so `e.OriginalSource` will return a `Border` element (or something else depending where you double click). The correct member was `Source`, which is the Chart itself (after the event bubbled up through the layers of the chart control).

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger setters with the aptly named Trigger class.  Trigger (and DataTrigger, which operates similarly but on non dependency properties that implement INotifyPropertyChanged) can be used to monitor a property for a specific value and, should the value change to a given value, can enact a series of setters.

An easy way to accomplish this would be to use a data trigger that monitors your "backing object" property for being set to a non-null value.  When this happen, your setter would / should be applied.

Comment: you can only compare to equality on DataTrigger, so it would be kind of hard to compare to not null :-/ I found a custom binding class for that but that seems a bit over the top.

Comment: Custom converter?  It's actually really common.  I'm working on a  heavyweight WPF application, some of the most common converters are boolean to visibility, not null (with an invert parameter), etc.